# How can I flute my own dowel or create dowel with similar properties

Tags: joinery, dowel

Now I know that I can just buy these in packs of hundreds likely but lets play pretend that I need to make some from what I had available. When I think of fluted dowel I picture these guys...

[image: fluted dowel pins]

<sup>Image from [HomeDepot.com](http://www.homedepot.com/p/General-Tools-1-13-in-x-1-4-in-Fluted-Dowel-Pins-840014/202252099)</sup>

That style of dowel would be difficult to emulate. I am not going to make a jig where I would rotate the dowel and run a beading moulding plane, or similar tool, to scratch a groove in. [If they are actually compressed](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/a/3839/128) maybe I just need to compress them with something? Is there another method of working the dowel that will get a similar functional result?

Comment: If you need LOTS you could considering finding machinery to produce them:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=77_DkBDM5Nk https://www.brusa.it/en/woodworking-machines/special-woodworking-machines/spi-line-for-dowels-production

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> That style of dowel would be difficult to emulate.

Not so much actually! You can do a decent job of simulating this texture by simply gripping the dowel in pliers, vice-grips etc. and drawing it through, or squeezing hard to compress them into the wood.

Here's that tip in an old issue of Popular Mechanics, with another technique underneath:

[image: Two methods to groove dowels]

[**Source:** Popular Mechanics, Dec 1987]

Both tips are often repeated online and sent in to the tips sections of woodworking mags :-)

In either case you end up with some grooves that prevent a hydraulic seal from forming, allowing air and excess glue out of the drilled hole.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there another method of working the dowel that will get a similar functional result?

You could maybe make a [dowel plate](https://www.lie-nielsen.com/product/dowel-plate-standard),

[image: dowel plate]

but instead of drilling a regular hole through the steel plate, make a series of smaller holes in a circle that approximate the cross-section profile you're going for, then punch out the section where the dowel goes through.

Or, going with the dowel plate idea again, drill a normal hole and use a small circular file to get the same effect as drilling a series of smaller holes.

Comment: This would be the more reliable and repeatable approach. I wonder if it matters if the grooves are cut vs compressed.

Comment: @Matt, one might argue that a compressed dowel is stronger, but that might be a stretch.  I imagine that the compressing operation is just a timesaver for mass manufacturing.

Comment: The compression is supposedly helpful when the glue is present. The compressed areas re-expand, leaving a stronger bond. (I read that on another answer here; I have no actual knowledge of this myself.)

Answer (score 1):

> If they are actually compressed maybe I just need to compress them with something

Up until I read that answer I had never considered them to be compressed. I had always assumed cut.

If that is the case then a simple approach to this would be to file (or fine rasp) the ends to get the taper and the use a large toothed jawed tool, like pliers, to simply compress the dowel. This needs to be done carefully as to not break the dowel.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the dowel to be fluted?
If you are worried about blowout (glue/ hydraulic pressure buildup) just plane a small flat spot on the dowel.